# In node.js how to get/construct URL string from WHATWG URL including user and password but nothing after host

Tags: node.js, parsing, url, format

What would be the recommended way of deriving the following:

```
https://user:pass@hostname:port
```

From:

```
https://user:pass@hostname:port/p/a/t/h?q=whatevere#hash
```

when dealing with node.js `url` module using current WHATWG URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can use standard javascript with node.js

```
  var s = 'https://user:pass@hostname:port/path#hash';
  s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

That should give you s as the value you want.

Caz

Update -

You could also do this if you can't predict the number of / in the URL

```
var url = 'https://user:pass@hostname:port/p/a/t/h?q=whatevere#hash';
url = url.split( '/' )[2];
```

What that does is creates an array from that string using / as the deliminator. So url[0] would be https: url[1] would be blank as its between the two / and url[2] will be user:pass@hostname:port

So if you don't need the http part you can do that and even do something like this is the https is important

```
var url = 'https://user:pass@hostname:port/p/a/t/h?q=whatevere#hash';
url = url.split( '/' )[2];
var urlstring = 'https://' + url
```

Comment: oh sorry where i have 'path' that could have multiple slashes. I'll amend question to clarify

Comment: so with your suggestion i get back everything except the last part of the path: 'https://user:pass@hostname:port/p/a/t`

Comment: Do you know the amount of slashes you will have? Or can it be variable?

Comment: Thanks Caz, i like your getting back to basic string manipulation approach. For some reason i had thought using the node URL constructor might make life easier, but i think you are right, and i should just extract the relevant part of the url string using str.split() etc

Comment: i think your reference to 'standard jquery' is unnecessary. Can you change that to just 'standard javascript' ?

Comment: ...ok? javascript it is then

Answer (score 4):

As of Node 8.x with the WHATWG URL API:

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const url = new URL('https://user:pass@hostname:1234/p/a/t/h?q=whatevere#hash');
url.search = url.pathname = url.hash = '';
console.log(url.toString()); // https://user:pass@hostname:1234/
```