# node legacy url.parse deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

`require('url').parse('someurl.com/page')` have been docs-only deprecated, and our strict linter is unhappy about it... I have tried to replace it in our code with what the internet suggests `new URL('someurl.com/page')` which works in most cases.

However, we have examples where the url is a local image `some/image.png` and that was working nicely with url.parse() and returns:

```
Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/some/image.png',
  path: '/some/image.png',
  href: '/some/image.png'
}
```

But the suggested replacement `new URL('some/image.png')` throws a type error...

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL] [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL:
> /some/image.png

url.parse is doing some validation and accept local paths, but the new url constructor does not. What to do ?

Answer (score 35):

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   const baseURL =  req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + '/';
   const reqUrl = new URL(req.url,baseURL);
   console.log(reqUrl);
});
```

will give reqUrl :

```
URL {
  href: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico',
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '3000',
  pathname: '/favicon.ico',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

Comment: `baseURL = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + '/';` would probably be more correct, as request could actually be `https`.

Comment: the req.protocol is undefined

Comment: use `'https'` instead of `req.protocol`

Answer (score 17):

You can use the base parameter of the URL constructor. For example:

```
new URL('some/image-png', "https://dummyurl.com")
```

For more info, https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_url_input_base.

Comment: But I need an API that does not require me to know the domain name ;c. I don't want to rely on hardcode or environment variables for such task.

Comment: @Klesun https://github.com/alwinb/reurl and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196706/new-url-whatwg-url-api/51525433#51525433 and https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/531

Comment: Even though I know that it's not really a URL when you don't have the base, I wonder why they don't provide an alternative other than using a fake dummy website.

Comment: @Klesun the input base is optional.See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73914067/2441641

Answer (score 8):

#### This is how to get the query string params without using any external modules

```js
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = new URL(req.url, `http://${req.headers.host}/`);

  const query = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
  console.log(query.entries());

  res.end("I am done");
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: This approach matches the [usage example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageurl) in nodejs documentation, though the authors [do admit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/44919#discussion_r1059583020) that it's "not a particularly elegant one".

Answer (score 7):

```
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

const p = path.join("public", "images", "a.jpg");

console.log(p);                                     // public\images\a.jpg
console.log(new url.URL(p, "http://xxx").pathname); // /public/images/a.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `new URL` to parse get all data:

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   const parsedUrl = new URL(req.url, `https://${req.headers.host}/`);
   console.log(parsedUrl);
});
```

And `parsedUrl` will consist all URL's data:

```js
{
  href: 'https://localhost:5000/getIPData/?param=value',
  origin: 'https://localhost:5000',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost:5000',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '5000',
  pathname: '/getIPData/',
  search: '?param=value',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'param' => 'value' },
  hash: ''
}
```

Use `http` or `https` prefix depending on your protocol.

By the way, for getting query params values use:

```js
parsedUrl.searchParams.get('param')
```

Answer (score -1):

On **Node v16.17.1**.

This is what works for me:

```js
const { URL } = require('url');

const url = new URL('https://somewebsite.com/params?x=x')
```