# Node.js "url.parse" replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, deprecated

I am learning about node.js, but I think the guide that I was following was slightly outdated. It seems that the "url.parse" method has been deprecated and even through google searches I could not understand which is the appropriate replacement for it, and how to apply it to my code:

```
const http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  url = require('url');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  let addr = request.url,
    q = url.parse(addr, true),
    filePath = '';
```

All help is appreciate it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node legacy url.parse deprecated, what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375013/node-legacy-url-parse-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: I saw that while looking up for a solution, I guess I just dont understand how to apply it to my code for it to work.

Comment: instead of using ```url.parse```, create a new URL object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the newURL() API. More about this can be found here https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api

In the given code snippet, it can be used as follows:

```
const http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
const { url } = require('url');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  let addr = request.url,
  q = new url(addr),
  filePath = '';
})
```